# Kafka topic is getting deleted automatically in the regression setup

Tags: java, apache-kafka, regression

Six Kafka topics are available in the system, and only one of them is automatically deleted in the regression setup just after starting the Kafka cluster. However, when I attempted to recreate it locally, it failed. That topic is accessible in the local environment till the environment is deleted.

The error log as below.

```
Deleted log /x01/exch/data/broker_1/20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0.22885369517b432e8ac75fed76e7c8a1-delete/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)

 

[2023-08-09 10:04:45,644] INFO [Log partition=20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0, dir=/x01/exch/data/broker_1] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2023-08-09 10:04:45,645] INFO Created log for partition 20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0 in /x01/exch/data/broker_1/20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0 with properties {compression.type -> producer, min.insync.replicas -> 1, message.downconversion.enable -> true, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, cleanup.policy -> [delete], flush.ms -> 9223372036854775807, retention.ms -> 604800000, segment.bytes -> 1073741824, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807, message.format.version -> 2.7-IV2, max.compaction.lag.ms -> 9223372036854775807, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, max.message.bytes -> 1048588, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, preallocate -> false, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, unclean.leader.election.enable -> false, retention.bytes -> -1, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, segment.ms -> 604800000, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
 

[2023-08-09 10:04:46,305] INFO Log for partition 20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0 is renamed to /x01/exch/data/broker_1/20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0.22885369517b432e8ac75fed76e7c8a1-delete and is scheduled for deletion (kafka.log.LogManager)

 
[2023-08-09 10:05:46,306] INFO [Log partition=20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0, dir=/x01/exch/data/broker_1] Deleting segments as the log has been deleted: LogSegment(baseOffset=0, size=0, lastModifiedTime=1691555685640, largestRecordTimestamp=None) (kafka.log.Log)
[2023-08-09 10:05:46,307] INFO [Log partition=20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0, dir=/x01/exch/data/broker_1] Deleting segment files LogSegment(baseOffset=0, size=0, lastModifiedTime=1691555685640, largestRecordTimestamp=None) (kafka.log.Log)
[2023-08-09 10:05:46,307] INFO Deleted log /x01/exch/data/broker_1/20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0.22885369517b432e8ac75fed76e7c8a1-delete/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2023-08-09 10:05:46,307] INFO Deleted offset index /x01/exch/data/broker_1/20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0.22885369517b432e8ac75fed76e7c8a1-delete/00000000000000000000.index.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2023-08-09 10:05:46,307] INFO Deleted time index /x01/exch/data/broker_1/20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0.22885369517b432e8ac75fed76e7c8a1-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2023-08-09 10:05:46,307] INFO Deleted log for partition 20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0 in /x01/exch/data/broker_1/20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-user_info-0.22885369517b432e8ac75fed76e7c8a1-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-08-09 10:05:46,307] INFO [Log partition=20230809-eu-pdc-dsgom-p1-quote_block-0, dir=/x01/exch/data/broker_1] Deleting segments as the log has been deleted: LogSegment(baseOffset=0, size=0, lastModifiedTime=1691555685594, largestRecordTimestamp=None) (kafka.log.Log)
```

What are the scenarios that could possibly occur?